# how to get youtube playlist video id with video title

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-data-api

[image]

I need how to retrieved YouTube playlist video id and Video title using API key, if only  we need last five updated videos in a YouTube playlist. How to got it please give me a perfect link so that I achieve this. 
our code in below

```
enter code here
```

```html
<script>
var channelName = 'mipaltan';
var vidHeight = 350;
var vidWidth = 650;
var vidMaxResult =7; // Maximum can be 50

$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
part: 'contentDetails',
forUsername: channelName,
key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg' //Browser API Key
},
function (data) {
$.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
console.log(item); // See in Browser Console
pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
getVideos(pid);
})
}
);
function getVideos(pid) {
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",
{
part: 'snippet',
maxResults: vidMaxResult,
playlistId: pid,
key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg' //Browser API Key
},
function (data) {
var outputVideo;
$.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
console.log(item); // See in Browser Console
vidId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
thumbnails = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
texturl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidId;
mainurl = "'" + texturl + "'";
outputVideo = '<div style="float:left"><img style="width: 93px;height:65px; border-radius: 5px;margin-right:1px;" src="' + thumbnails + '"onclick="newSrc(' + mainurl + ')" /></div>';

$('#result').append(outputVideo);
})
}

);
}
});

</script>
<script>
function newSrc(testurl) {
document.getElementById("MyFrame").src = testurl;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<iframe id="MyFrame"; width="670"; height="350"; src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yx9M-6cx8wA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div style="padding-left:5px", id="result" class ="footer-widget">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like so far? Do you get any error messages? Please give something to work with. StackOverflow is not about getting people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and added jQuery. Console shows you have already archieved your goal?

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var channelName = 'mipaltan';
var vidHeight = 350;
var vidWidth = 650;
var vidMaxResult =7; // Maximum can be 50

$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
part: 'contentDetails',
forUsername: channelName,
key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg' //Browser API Key
},
function (data) {
$.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
console.log(item); // See in Browser Console
pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
getVideos(pid);
})
}
);
function getVideos(pid) {
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",
{
part: 'snippet',
maxResults: vidMaxResult,
playlistId: pid,
key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg' //Browser API Key
},
function (data) {
var outputVideo;
$.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
console.log(item); // See in Browser Console
vidId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
thumbnails = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
texturl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidId;
mainurl = "'" + texturl + "'";
outputVideo = '<div style="float:left"><img style="width: 93px;height:65px; border-radius: 5px;margin-right:1px;" src="' + thumbnails + '"onclick="newSrc(' + mainurl + ')" /></div>';

$('#result').append(outputVideo);
})
}

);
}
});

</script>
<script>
function newSrc(testurl) {
document.getElementById("MyFrame").src = testurl;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<iframe id="MyFrame"; width="670"; height="350"; src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yx9M-6cx8wA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div style="padding-left:5px", id="result" class ="footer-widget">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```